# reading a file line by line from a shell script

Tags: bash

I am facing a problem in a bash shell script. This script is supposed to execute another shell script (./script here) and the output of the script is redirected to a file(tmp). Then the file should be read line by line and for each of the lines the same script(./script) should be executed giving the line as argument and the result should be stored in a file(tmp1). Eventually these results should be appended to the first file(tmp).

I am pasting my script below:

```
./script $1 $2 > tmp
cat tmp | while read a
do
 ./script $a $2 >> tmp1
done

cat tmp1 | while read line
do
 ./script $line $2 >> tmp
done
```

I get the following error when I execute the script "./script: line 11: syntax error: unexpected end of file"

Can anyone please help me out in this??

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: show your "wiki" and "script" scripts. !!

Comment: I answered this below.. I dunno the contents of the java file it executes. I am only interested in the output it produces.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The script file has DOS/Windows line endings. Try this command, then run your script:

```
dos2unix ./script
```

You're probably editing the file using a Windows editor and that's adding `\r` (0x0d) to the end of each line. This can be removed by using `dos2unix`.

Comment: @ghostdog74: I created a test script consisting of a `while` loop and ran the reverse (`unix2dos`) on it. When I ran the result under `dash` and `bash` they both gave unexpected EOF errors.

Answer (score 1):

The shell splits on whitespace normally. You can make it split on newlines by writing, towards the top,

```
IFS='
'
```

However, I think what you're trying to do might not be appropriate for shell, and might be better served by Perl or Ruby.

Comment: hey.. thanks for your reply. 

The problem with Perl or Ruby is that I do not know any of those two languages :P, so it will take some time learning them.

Comment: what you want to do can be done with the shell, if you don't know other languages, stick to shell.

Comment: hey... using your solution, I get the following errors
": command not found: 
./wiki_tree: line 12: syntax error near unexpected token `done'
./wiki_tree: line 12: `done'
"

Comment: @ghostdog74: From the description given, it's a recursive shell script, which is a little boggling.

@assassin: Yeah, gonna need some more information here, then.

Answer (score 1):

lose all the cats! they are unnecessary. And i suppose summ_tmp is an existing file?

```
#!/bin/bash
set -x
./wiki $1 $2 > tmp
while read -r a
do
    ./wiki $a $2 >> tmp1
done < summ_tmp

while read -r line
do
    ./wiki $line $2 >> tmp
done < tmp1
```

With what you are doing, you might want to refactor your "./script" to eliminate unnecessary steps. If its not too long, show what your "./script" does. Show your desired output and show examples of relevant input files where possible

Put set -x in your script (wiki and ./script) to help you debug.

Comment: Hi,
I get the following error when I execute your script:
./wiki_tree: line 5: syntax error near unexpected token `done'      
'/wiki_tree: line 5: `done < summ_tmp

Comment: comment out all the while loops, and execute only wiki. What did you see? Show all relevant information, like what is wiki, and script.

Comment: after commenting out all the while loops, it works.... btw ./wiki and ./script are the same (I m sorry fr this mistake). I renamed script to wiki...

Comment: script (or wiki, watever) calls a runs a java class file.

Comment: set -x... ummm could you please temme where should I put it? I am pretty new to shell scripting.

Comment: so add in the while loops one at a time and run the script until the point error occurs. show your java output if possible. As for the set -x, see my edit. Is your wiki script a full shell script or does it run only one java command? If its a full shell script, put set -x as well.

Comment: for the set -x line, this is the error I get:
: invalid optione 3: set: -
set: usage: set [--abefhkmnptuvxBCHP] [-o option] [arg ...]
Rest other errors are the same as before

Comment: set -x is a bash option. If you have error, then you are not using bash. check your shebang make sure its #!/bin/bash. tell us what shell you are using.!

Comment: As far as I know, I am using bash shell... I checked ps -x for that... but what is shebang? and where is it?

Comment: see my code. its the first line. #!/bin/bash. make sure you have it in all your scripts if you are calling your script with dot slash (./script)

Comment: I get this error if I put that in the first line.
: bad interpreter: No such file or directory

Comment: on the command line, type `which bash`. use that path instead of /bin/bash if its different.

Comment: I typed the command which bash and got the output as "/bin/bash" !!

Comment: "bad interpreter"?  Your OS doesn't want to execute bash scripts.  That always gets in the way of getting bash to solve your problems, you see?  ghostdog's code is righteous (though I follow the way of `while read -a`).  An idea: what does `ls -l $(which bash)` return?  And another: what does `cat /etc/shells` return?

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could use xargs - this executes a command on every line in a file, which is exactly what you want.

You can replace

```
cat tmp1 | while read line
do
    ./script $line $2 >> tmp
done
```

with

```
xargs <tmp1 -n1 -IXXX ./script XXX $2 >>tmp
```

`-n1` means read one line at a time from the input,

`-IXXX` means substitute XXX with the line that was read in - the default is to append it to the end of the command line.

Comment: it still shows this error: line 5: syntax error: unexpected end of file. How do we denote that our script has ended in bash scripting?? Maybe thats the problem

Comment: @OP, put set -x in your script to help you debug

Comment: set -x... ummm could you please temme where should I put it? I am pretty new to shell scripting